# Wifi Not Working, but my mobile hotspot is.?

Tags: wireless

Just booted Ubuntu (Studio) 17.04 64bit and my system isn't connecting to my router. My i/o is working, the system sees my Wifi jungle, only I can't connect. Usually it connects without a hitch with 16.10 but now I get no connection. Funny thing is, my Mobile Hotspot works fine. Any clues?